# Windows 8 xaml app issue with MultipartFormDataContent not uploading image

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, winrt-xaml

I am trying to upload an image file from the users local folder

I wrote this method that gets the file stream and the url, and then uploads it.
The problem is, although I get no error and the image on the server gets its own id etc., it appears empty.

I assumed there was something wrong with the stream I upload, when I set a breakpoint there I see the bytes inside it, so its not empty

```
public static async Task<string> UploadImage(string url, StorageFile file)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authKey);
        try
        {   
            IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            form.Add(new StringContent("name"), "myphoto");
            var content = readStream.AsStream();
            form.Add(new StreamContent(content));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, form);
            string res = response.Content.ToString();
            return res;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;   
        }            
    }
```

Comment: not sure if it's this simple, but looking at posts of similar code (but different errors), I'm seeing the StreamContent constructor use the overload that adds the length.  Also, have you run Fiddler to confirm the bytes are actually in the POST http packet?

Comment: you are right, the bytes weren't in the http packet. now I changed it adding new ByteArrayContent(bytes2,0,bytes2.Length) instead of streamcontent, it contains the bytes. unfortunately now I get a 404 error. I think I have to add the content type somehow to image/jpeg

Comment: possibly, would depend on the service your going to and how it's doing the request routing

Comment: there was a problem with the service, now it works! it was not an app issue. should I delete the question now?

Comment: no, I'd follow up and answer your own question with the new information.  The fact that an error on the service end was manifesting itself as such could still be useful information to someone else running into a similar error scenario on their service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a web service problem after all